# how to store session in the webform and retrieve in the CS page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having 3-4 Links  in aspx pages and i want on click of every links it store the Session on webform or the hiddenfield which i have to get the Session or hiddenfeild on the CS page and do the needful.

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="../Admin/Home.aspx" id="a_Home" class="homeactive" onclick="ChangeSelectedMenuCss(this.id);">
        Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../Admin/subadmindetails.aspx" id="a_Report" class="home" onclick="ChangeSelectedMenuCss(this.id);">
        SubAdmin</a></li>
    <li><a href="../Admin/control_panel.aspx" id="a_User" class="home" onclick="ChangeSelectedMenuCss(this.id);">
        Control Panel</a></li>
    <li><a href="../Admin/admin_master.aspx" id="a_CntrlPnl" class="home" onclick="ChangeSelectedMenuCss(this.id);">
        Master Data</a></li>
    <li><a href="../Admin/Login.aspx" class="home">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks and regrads :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want on click of every links it store the Session

You need link buttons to make that, and not simple links

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

and on code behind

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // save your session variable
    Session["var"] = "1";
    // move to the page you like
    Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx");
}
```

### Other approch

This is the solution on your question, how ever you can avoid that and simple on the page load on the ending page you can save your variables to session. For example, lets say that you have this link and the user is click on that link and go to home.aspx

```
<a href="../Admin/Home.aspx" >Home</a>
```

then inside the `home.aspx` you have on code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["var"] = "1";
}
```

### Pass parameters

And one more solution is to pass parameters to the url links, for example you can do something like:

```
<a href="../Admin/Home.aspx?var=1" >Home</a>
```

and on code behind read and save the "var" parameter.

Comment: thanx for ur reply but as u seeing here there are lots of Links so for every link i have to get the Click event that is why i want to store in the aspx page and get the respected value

Comment: this is the only way to do that.. Thank u so much for ur reply..:)